# using less with symfony2 on windows

Tags: php, node.js, symfony, less, assetic

Im trying to get Less with assetic working while developing on a windows OS.

Im loading an existing project of which I can alter the config.yml and parameters.yml files as necessary.

steps so far:

1. I have installed Node.js via the msi installer
2. I have used npm and installed less gloabally

**config.yml**

```
assetic:
      debug:          %kernel.debug%
      use_controller: false
      bundles:        [ FOSUserBundle ]
      filters:
          less:
              node: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" #/usr/local/bin/node
              node_paths: [C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\less] #[ /usr/local/lib/node_modules ]
              apply_to: "\.less$"
```

Ive tried moving the `appdata/roaming/npm/node_modules/less` dir straight into the local `node_modules` dir in `program files (x86)/nodejs/node_modules` dir to no avail.

Ive also tried setting adding the `roaming/npm/node_modules/less` dir to the environment path, no joy.

Ive tried installing `less` directly into the project and pointing the node_path directly to it, no joy.

the error in the outputted css file is as below:

> [exception] 500 | Internal Server Error | Assetic\Exception\FilterException
>   [message] An error occurred while running:
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Temp\assEC1E.tmp"

(which is rather unhelpful)

any help appreciated, we're all a bit stuck in the office.

Comment: not talking about the UNIX tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question but, as I've found the same problem and I finally solved it, I wanted to post the answer.

The recommended way to use LESS on Windows  is to use lessphp package. To add it you just add in your composer json the following line:

```
"require": {
    .....
    "leafo/lessphp": "dev-master",
    .....
}
```

Then you must run

```
$ php composer.phar update
```

and update your `app/config/config.yml` with this configuration:

```
assetic:
    #...
    filters:
        lessphp:
            file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php
            apply_to: "\.less$"
```

Once you have do this, you will be able to preprocess the LESS files and generate the CSS files.

Then when you want to process the files with assetic you just have to include that filter in your views like, for example:

```
{% stylesheets filter='lessphp' output='css/main.css'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/less/*'
%}
```