# cannot setup lessphp in symfony2

Tags: symfony, lessphp

following on from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27271077/using-less-with-symfony2-on-windows) I have been asked to try to implement lessphp to see if its compatible with the current build of the commercial application (it wasnt when it was originally developed).

Ive installed the bundle with composer successfully and set up config as per instructions as follows:

`filters:
        lessphp:
            file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php
            apply_to: "\.less$"
            # Formatter options: compressed, lessjs, classic
            formatter: "compressed"
            preserve_comments: false`

Ive confirmed that the less main class is loading fine with a good ol' die statement.

but Im getting the following error when trying to `assetic/dump`.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Assetic\Filter\LessphpFilter::setLoadPaths() in C:\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\SBSonline\sbsonline-v2\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 118

Call Stack:
    0.0002     126720   1. {main}() C:\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\SBSonline\sbsonline-v2\app\console:0
    0.0150    1257016   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() C:\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\SBSonline\sbsonline-v2\app\console:22
    0.0187    1405928   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() C:\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\SBSonline\sbsonline-v2\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:105
    3.2818   28230888   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() C:\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\SBSonline\sbsonline-v2\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:78
    3.2841   28231512   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() C:\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\SBSonline\sbsonline-v2\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:199
    3.2844   28233736   6. Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Command\DumpCommand->initialize() C:\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\SBSonline\sbsonline-v2\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php:227
    3.2844   28233960   7. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() C:\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\SBSonline\sbsonline-v2\vendor\symfony\assetic-bundle\Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Command\DumpCommand.php:53
    3.2845   28234360   8. appDevDebugProjectContainer->getAssetic_AssetManagerService() C:\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\SBSonline\sbsonline-v2\app\bootstrap.php.cache:211
    3.2845   28234424   9. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() C:\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\SBSonline\sbsonline-v2\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php:61
    3.2845   28234768  10. appDevDebugProjectContainer->getAssetic_AssetFactoryService() C:\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\SBSonline\sbsonline-v2\app\bootstrap.php.cache:211
    3.2845   28235776  11. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() C:\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\SBSonline\sbsonline-v2\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php:3700
    3.2845   28236112  12. appDevDebugProjectContainer->getAssetic_Filter_LessphpService() C:\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\SBSonline\sbsonline-v2\app\bootstrap.php.cache:211
```

could anyone help please? I have a feeling that Im missing something obvious but I cant find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok weird.

according to the documentation for [lessphp](http://api.drupalecommerce.org/api/drupal/drupal!core!vendor!kriswallsmith!assetic!src!Assetic!Filter!LessphpFilter.php/function/LessphpFilter%3A%3AsetLoadPaths/8.x) there should have been a function obviously called `::setLoadPaths()`.

It wasnt there so Ive added it manually.

Its now trying to parse the files.